# Printing pixel values out but the image is overlapping. Image is three times the size it should be

Tags: c++, image, buffer, overlap

Good day everyone. I managed to print out pixel values(int from byte) from my fingerprint reader and displaying it as image. The text file that contains the pixel values is triple the size that it should be. And the pictures are overlapping. May I know what's wrong??? Here's the code. By the way the raw image is supposed to be 150K byte (480x320pixel).

According to the specification, the image is 8bit 256grayscale.

I suspect it has something to do with the size of the pBuffer which stores the raw image. Please help, I don't know how to solve this.

I used

```
 sizeof(pBuffer)
```

it returns a value of four. And there are four same images overlapping. All i want is one image.

```
void main()
{
ofstream rawImage("Raw image.txt",ios::out);

 PBYTE pvData = (PBYTE)pBuffer;//pBuffer stores the raw image
byte *bPoint = (byte*) pvData;

byte TempArr[153600];
byte *bTo = TempArr;
int Int32[153600];
memcpy(bTo, bPoint, 153600);
for(int i=0;i<153600;i++)
{

Int32[i] = (int)TempArr[i];
rawImage<<" "<<Int32[i];
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(pBuffer)` just gives you the (4 bytes) size of the pointer!! That's probably not what you want.

Comment: hi @πάνταῥεῖ, how can i get only the bytes of the pointer that matters? Btw, the image format is 8bit 256 grayscale.

Comment: _' how can i get only the bytes of the pointer that matters?'_ Sorry I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, how can i get the value so that i can print out exactly 1 image instead of 4 images overlapping? thanks =D

Comment: Take a step back and reason how many ASCII characters are required to write an 8-bit value.  Also ponder if the program that displays the text file content may have a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Solved the problem. It is the device datasheet problem. The device specified that it is 480x320 but in the real case it is 320x480. That's what caused the overlapping images. Took so long to solve this problem. And btw thanks guys for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted writes a *text* file containing 150K numbers separated by spaces. If the numbers in decimal form typically have 2 digits, that explains the size of your file.

In case you want to write a binary file (containing 150K bytes), you should

- Not call it `.txt`
- open it with `ios::out | ios::binary`
- call the `write` method for the whole block or the `put` method for single characters instead of using the formatted output operator `<<`

Comment: _'`ios::binary`'_ That matters for windows only AFAIR. To write binary values use `std::ostream::write()` instead of `std::ostream::operator<<()` as you mentioned.

Comment: hi michael, I tried to write it in binary by using fwrite with fopen_s with "wb+" parameters. But i don't know how to make these binary values to get the image. Like ".bmp" or ".jpg" format. Any method to do this?

Comment: I only know how to get the image thru the pixel values that i get in the text file by using openCV

Comment: If you are able to read the text file in openCV and it is around 500KB, writing works fine. In that case, your problem is not in writing the data to the file, but at the data acquisition step.